# Laravel File Upload different versions and formats of a file

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Let me know a sample. how can I store the uploaded file to the database; laravel 
ex.
In the system, if upload a doc file, it will automatically convert to PDF.(via cloud convert API ). how I can save both files in the database.

```
   ---------------------------------------------------
   |id|proposal_id|version_id|Status|fileName|filetype| 
   ---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to upload the files in a folder within the public folder and save the link folder in the database
you can use code like this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
        $destinationPath = 'image/'; // upload path
        $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $logofileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renaming image
        Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $logofileName);
    }
```